# Why do I get command not found when using the cut command?

Tags: bash, shell-script, rhel

I'm in the process of writing a script that checks the maximum number of days between password change using the value in field 5 for the account in `etc/shadow`. I have

```
MaxNumOfDays=$(cut -d: -f1,5 /etc/shadow | grep -v '.*admin')
```

declared. But when I try

```
for account in $MaxNumOfDays ; do
    max_num_of_days=$(echo $account | cut: -d: -f2)
    echo max_num_of_days
done
```

I get

```
line 27: cut:: command not found
max_num_of_days`
```

Any reason why I get that error?

Comment: If one of the answers solved your problem, please upvote them.

Comment: Downvoted: just re-read your script before requesting help on internet ...

Comment: @Eduardo the OP doesn’t have enough rep to upvote; but they can accept an answer ;-).

Comment: You're right @StephenKitt, that's what I meant :). I'm myself a pretty new contributor.

Comment: @Eduardo heh, a few months ago I discovered I’d actually forgotten that upvoting requires a small amount of reputation, so brand new contributors can’t upvote! It’s not only new contributors who can be unfamiliar with SE’s way of working...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re trying to run `cut:`, not `cut`; the former doesn’t exist. You need to remove the extra `:`.